# IBM Worklight - Using a Progress bar instead of busy indicator?

Tags: mobile, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

Can anyone suggest me how to use progress bar to show progress?

In my app, when a user launches the app for the first time it downloads 12 MB of data via  multiple web service, and the download can take 3 to 4 minutes. Right now I am using WL busy indicator but to have good user experience, I think a progress bar is the best solution.

So can you tell me how to proceed?
Is it possible with WL? Do I need to use Dojo?

Comment: I suppose this may be beyond your control and neither here nor there, but a progress bar isn't really going to make a 3-4 minute wait time any better of a user experience...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worklight does not provide a progress bar UI widget - nor should it; Worklight is not that kind of a framework.

Since you added the `dojo` tag to your question, you can try implementing Dojo's [dijit/ProgressBar](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/ProgressBar.html). You will need to control when to show and hide it.

Comment: Or use [dojox/mobile/ProgressBar](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/ProgressBar.html), which might fit better on mobile devices than dijit's counterpart.